# python parse xml

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a basic script that can parse the temperature, dew point, altimeter, etc. However, how can I parse a conditional string like the sky condition? I'd like to parse the data and have it print: "Sky Condition: few at 2000 ft AGL" for example.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from urllib import urlopen

link = urlopen('http://weather.aero/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&       requestType=retrieve&format=xml&stationString=KSFO&hoursBeforeNow=1')

tree = ET.parse(link)
root = tree.getroot()

data = root.findall('data/METAR')
for metar in data:
    print metar.find('temp_c').text
```

Comment: You probably should include an illustrative XML sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page you are retrieving has a structure something like this:

```
<METAR>
  <!-- snip -->
  <sky_condition sky_cover="FEW" cloud_base_ft_agl="2000"/>
  <sky_condition sky_cover="BKN" cloud_base_ft_agl="18000"/>
</METAR>
```

So what you are asking is how to extract XML attributes. [The xml.etree.ElementTree docs](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects) states that these are stored in a dictionary called `attrib`. So your code would look something like this:

```
data = root.findall('data/METAR')
for sky in data.findall('sky_condition'):
    print "Sky Condition: {0} at {1} ft AGL".format(
        sky.attrib['sky_cover'],
        sky.attrib['cloud_base_ft_agl']
      )
```

Comment: Ah, beat me to it :) If you want to reduce lines even more, you could try  `print 'Sky Condition: {sky_cover} at cloud_base_ft_agl}'.format(**sky.attrib)`, but yours better fits the 'explicit is better than implicit' model.

Comment: @RocketDonkey It felt like there should have been a way to do that. I just forgot about the "unmapping" operator (`**`). +1

Comment: Ha, well I think your version does a better job of explaining, so +1 back atcha :)